# Why doesn't range-for find my overloads of begin and end for std::istream_iterator?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, istream-iterator

I have code like this

```
std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios_base::in);
if(file.good())
{
    file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new delimeter_tokens()));
    for(auto& entry : std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file))
    {
        std::cout << entry << std::endl;    
    }
}
file.close();
```

where `std::istream_iterator<std::string>`'s  `begin()` and `end()`
are defined as follows

```
template<class T>
std::istream_iterator<T> begin(std::istream_iterator<T>& stream)
{
    return stream;
}

template<class T>
std::istream_iterator<T> end(std::istream_iterator<T>& stream)
{
    return std::istream_iterator<T>();
}
```

which is what **Mark Nelson** has also written about in Dr. Dobb's [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/auto-types-and-range-based-for-statement/232900460?pgno=2). Alas, the code fails to compile on my Visual Studio 2012 with error messages

> error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'std::istream_iterator<_Ty>'

and

> error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'std::istream_iterator<_Ty>'

**Question:** Is there something I haven't noticed, bug in the compiler (unlikely, but just in case) or... Well, any ideas?

This questions is cleaned up considerably, as advised by [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500104/xeo). To provide more background and references this is related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269678/how-to-capture-0-2-groups-in-c-regular-expressions-and-print-them) on Stackoverflow, I was wondering how to make line based parsing cleaner than the usual loops. A bit of coding and checking from the internet, and I had a working sketch as follows

```
std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios_base::in);
if(file.good())
{               
    file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new delimeter_tokens()));
    for(auto& entry : istream_range<std::string>(file)
    {
        std::cout << entry << std::endl;    
    }
}
file.close();
```

but there was slight snag I tried to remedy. I think it would look more natural to write as in the code that fails to compile and not like

```
for(auto& entry : istream_range<std::string>(file)
```

Please, take a note of the different iterator. The **delimeter_tokens** is defined like [Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415784/nawaz) kindly has shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607589/right-way-to-split-an-stdstring-into-a-vectorstring) (code not duplicated) and **istream_range** as in Code Synthesis blog [here](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/05/16/cxx11-range-based-for-loop/). I think the begin and end implementations should work, as advertised in the aforementioned Code Synthesis blog post

> The last rule (the fallback to the free-standing begin()and end() functions) allows us to non-invasively adapt an existing container to the range-based for loop interface.

Thus my question with all the (ir)relevant background.

Comment: I took the liberty to change the question title to reflect the actual question asked. Roll back or change if necessary.

Comment: It's better like that, I think. It gets the attention of those who are seeking to a solution similar to mine and those who has the lookup problem to solve. How do I make your post as an answer (or does someone more accomplished do that)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ranged-for relies on ADL if the special handling for native array (`T foo[N]`) and member `begin`/`end` doesn't yield any results.

`§6.5.4 [stmt.ranged] p1`

> - otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, **where `begin` and `end` are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2)**. For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace `std` is an associated namespace.

Your problem is, that the associated namespace of `std::istream_iterator` is (obviously) `namespace std`, not the global namespace.

`§3.4.2 [basic.lookup.argdep] p2`

> For each argument type `T` in the function call, there is a set of zero or more associated namespaces and a set of zero or more associated classes to be considered. The sets of namespaces and classes is determined entirely by the types of the function arguments [...].
>
> - If `T` is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty.
> - **If `T` is a class type** (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. **Its associated namespaces are the namespaces of which its associated classes are members.** Furthermore, if T is a class template specialization, its associated namespaces and classes also include: the namespaces and classes associated with the types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters [...].

Note the last (quoted) part of the second bullet. It basically means that using a class which is a member of the global namespace as the template argument makes the code work:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
std::istream_iterator<T> begin(std::istream_iterator<T> is){
  return is;
}
template<class T>
std::istream_iterator<T> end(std::istream_iterator<T>){
  return std::istream_iterator<T>();
}

struct foo{};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, foo){
  return is;
}

int main(){
  for(foo f : std::istream_iterator<foo>(std::cin))
  //                                ^^^
  // make global namespace one of the associated namespaces
    ;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to follow you now. How would that namespace association trick work if I should read tokenized strings from the file stream? That is, the foo you point out in the loop should be strings in my case.

Comment: @Veksi: Basically, only the first part of my answer is important: You can't put overloads for `std` members in the global namespace for ranged-for. The second part was only to showcase a quirkyness of ADL that would allow that to work. :P

Comment: While commenting on [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18321288/819272), I found out about [*core issue* 1442](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1442) that changes the rules a little bit. Namespace `std` is no longer an associated namespace and [*it is explicitly mentioned that*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf) "begin
and end are looked up in the associated namespaces (3.4.2). [ Note: Ordinary unqualiﬁed lookup (3.4.1)
is not performed. — end note ]"

Answer (score 1):

Because of argument depended lookup the compiler tries to find `begin()` and `end()` in the `std` namespace. If you put your functions there, the code compiles.

Since name lookup is a complicated issue in C++ I'm not entirely sure if the compiler is behaving correctly or not.

Comment: You're not allowed to put overloads into `namespace std`.

Comment: But you can specialize templates, no?

Comment: @jrok: Yes, but only for your user-defined types, not for types that originate from `std` (IIRC). Also, you can't *partially* specialize function templates and function template specialization in general is frowned upon.