# How to allow range-for loop on my class?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
private:
    int a,b,c,d;
    char bar;
    double m,n
public:
    //constructors here
};
```

I wanna allow range-for loop on my class, e.g.

```
Foo foo {/*...*/};
for(auto& f : foo) {
  //f will be a specific order such as c,b,d,(int)m,(int)bar,a,(int)n
}
```

How can I achieve this? I was looking at iterator but don't know what are the requirements for a range-for loop. (Please don't ask me to use array or STL type)

Comment: You need an iterator type with `begin()` and `end()` exposure from your object class to enumerate the values in your (admittedly unusual) container. Perhaps an `std::array<int,4>` would better suit your needs.

Comment: You need a `begin` and `end` member function.

Comment: @Rapptz Is there any way to define how to iterate? begin and end in this case do not really apply...

Comment: @texasbruce Since you're opting for not using an array type it'll be difficult to.

Comment: @Rapptz I can use an array, but the data types are not the same in the class... Plus I need a specific order to iterate, not just from beginning to end. If I use an array, I might need to re-arrange the array and construct a temporary array and output, which will reduce the performance..

Comment: @texasbruce: To iterate over elements at runtime with a for loop of any sort, the elements must be all of the same type.  The closest you could come is a custom "for loop iteration" function with a functionoid callback.

Comment: @MooingDuck if you see the example, I cast them/ type conversion

Comment: @MooingDuck In the comment inside the for loop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The loop is defined to be equivalent to:

```
for ( auto __begin = <begin-expr>,
           __end = <end-expr>;
      __begin != __end;
      ++__begin ) {
    auto& f = *__begin;
    // loop body
}
```

where `<begin-expr>` is `foo.begin()`, or `begin(foo)` if there isn't a suitable member function, and likewise for `<end-expr>`. (This is a simplification of the specification in C++11 6.5.4, for this particular case where the range is a *lvalue* of class type).

So you need to define an iterator type that supports pre-increment `++it`, dereference `*it` and comparison `i1 != i2`; and either

- give `foo` public member functions `begin()` and `end()`; or
- define non-member functions `begin(foo)` and `end(foo)`, in the same namespace as `foo` so that they can be found by argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: So an iterator type with `begin()`, `end()`, `++`, `*` and `!=` ?

Comment: Thanks.. lemme try it. Will post the final answer when it works

Comment: @texasbruce: `begin()` and `end()` go on your container class, not your iterator.

Comment: [Global begin/end don't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=4b0aac7ff768cc17e80ed00a3b0f0b81-c96156d6cc95286981b0e9deef2eefae) because ordinary lookup is not being performed, only ADL with `std` as an associated namespace

Comment: @TemplateRex: It seems you're right. I'd assumed the lookup would include the global namespace, but I guess it means stictly ADL only.

Comment: I wrote iterators http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=48cd98af87c5135107c0841fde925c48-798d134e7828076b2f58250fd9f622f2

Comment: BTW, there is [*core issue* 1442](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1442) that changes the rules a little bit. Namespace `std` is no longer an associated namespace and [*it is explicitly mentioned that*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf) "begin
and end are looked up in the associated namespaces (3.4.2). [ Note: Ordinary unqualiﬁed lookup (3.4.1)
is not performed. — end note ]"

Comment: Thanks it worked! begin and end return 2 iterators, and iterators have ++,!=,* operators (++ and * both require to return reference)

Answer (score 1):

This seems fairly un-C++-like, and rather prone to breakage. What if the iteration order is changed (accidentally or not) during some update in the future? Clients relying on a specific order will break.

All that said if you wish to support this all you have to do is implement your own iterator and provide `begin`/`end` methods (or free functions with those names) to provide access. Then the iterator takes care of remembering which attribute it's currently looking at and provides it when dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic framework I came up with:

```
#include <iterator>

struct Foo;

template<typename Type>
struct MemberPtrBase {
    virtual ~MemberPtrBase() { }

    virtual Type get() const = 0;
    virtual MemberPtrBase & set(Type const &) = 0;
};

template<typename Class, typename RealType, typename CommonType>
struct MemberPtr : MemberPtrBase<CommonType> {
public:
    MemberPtr(Class * object, RealType(Class::*member))
    : m_object(object), m_ptr(member)
    { }

    CommonType get() const {
        return m_object->*m_ptr;
    }

    MemberPtr & set(CommonType const & val) {
        m_object->*m_ptr = val;
        return *this;
    }

    MemberPtr & operator=(RealType const & val) {
        return set(val);
    }

    operator CommonType() const {
        return get();
    }
private:
    Class * m_object;
    RealType (Class::*m_ptr);
};

template<typename Class, typename... Types>
struct MemberIterator {
public:
    using CommonType = typename std::common_type<Types...>::type;
public:
    MemberIterator(Class & obj, std::size_t idx, Types(Class::*...member))
    : m_object(obj), m_index(idx), m_members { new MemberPtr<Class, Types, CommonType>(&obj, member)... }
    { }

    MemberPtrBase<CommonType> & operator*() const {
        return *m_members[m_index];
    }

    bool operator==(MemberIterator const & it) const {
        return (&m_object == &it.m_object) && (m_index == it.m_index);
    }

    bool operator!=(MemberIterator const & it) const {
        return (&m_object != &it.m_object) || (m_index != it.m_index);
    }

    MemberIterator & operator++() {
        ++m_index;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Class & m_object;
    std::size_t m_index;
    MemberPtrBase<CommonType> * m_members[sizeof...(Types)];
};

struct Foo {
public:
    using iterator = MemberIterator<Foo, int, int, int, int>;
public:
    Foo(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c), m_d(d)
    { }

    iterator begin() {
        return iterator(*this, 0, &Foo::m_b, &Foo::m_d, &Foo::m_c, &Foo::m_a);
    }

    iterator end() {
        return iterator(*this, 4, &Foo::m_b, &Foo::m_d, &Foo::m_c, &Foo::m_a);
    }
private:
    int m_a, m_b, m_c, m_d;
};
```

If you have a basic understanding of variadic templates, I think the code is self-explanatory.

Usage is simple:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    Foo foo { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    for(auto & mem : foo) {
        std::cout << mem.get() << std::endl;
        mem.set(3);
    }

    for(auto & mem : foo) {
        std::cout << mem.get() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

A POC can be found on [ideone](http://ideone.com/LIye7v)